# Foundation 5 - Should I change _settings.scss on a per-project basis?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, dry

I'm styling a page right now (developing using libsass), and I'm making changes to font-families, headers etc. For a lot of these changes, I notice that they can be altered in `_settings.scss`.

My question is, should I be making a bunch of changes to `_settings.scss` and also adding custom styles to `app.scss`? Its apparent that `app.scss` is really intended for app specific changes, but is `_settings.scss` also intended to be uses this way?

Comment: It would be constructive when people down-voted, if they gave a reason in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using _settings.scss as much as you can and create extra scss files for modules and include these in app.scss.

Answer (score 0):

You should customize Foundation through `_settings.scss`It's well documented with comments and since the settings can influence multiply css classes,  it's the best way to achieve consistency.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually understand that, but what I'm asking is, should I use both _settings.scss and app.scss?

Comment: @ChrisJAllen when you create a new project Foundation spawns both `_settings.scss` and `app.scss` for you to modify. Here's nice explanatory video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gx-9cgNlZlQ